# wy do i get [object HTMLParagraphElement] in one file while it works in another file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have made this partial for a node and express website this partial does what i want when i include it one file while in another it gives back [object HTMLParagraphElement] what could have i done wrong??

I am using express and ejs lint and its quite big code so please help me this is a slider which will make my website look much better.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/slider.css">
<img class="headerimage" src="/assets/img/landing/116.png" alt="Could       not find"></li>
<script>
var g=0;
var a=['/assets/img/landing/116.png','/assets/img/landing   /17.png','assets/img/landing/28.png','/assets/img/landing/36.png',
       '/assets/img/landing/72.png','/assets/img/landing/95.png','  /assets/img/landing/j12.jpg','/assets/img/landing/kiminonawa.jpg']
setInterval(slide,2000)
    function slide(){
    document.querySelector('.headerimage').setAttribute("src",a[g])
    g=g+1
    if(g==a.length){g=0}
    }
</script>
```

i want to rotate the pictures in the array

Comment: Probably something else going on, hard to tell unless you can recreate the error in a snipplet..

Comment: thats a gonna be a lot of code and i am not even sure if i am allowed to share some of the code i would have to ask someone in private anyway thanks for taking a look at it . i was just hoping to get the most general reasons why this might happen

Comment: Well you need to figure out why `HTMLParagraphElement` is different. do you happen to have multiple elements with `headerimage` ? Do you have invalid HTML mark up?